# android 1.6, back button and onActivityResult

Tags: android, back-button

I'm working on a project with android 1.6 as target.

So, I can't use

```
@Override public void onBackPressed(){...}
```

I'm starting an activity with

```
startActivityForResult(intent,requestcode)
```

And I wan't to get back some info with

```
@Override protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

the problem is the following:

-'Activity A' throws 'Activity B'

-during 'ActivityB' the hardware back button is pressed

-'Activity A's onActivityResult is called but I don't get any info in data (data==null)

I'm trying to put some extra info at 'Activity B's

```
@Override protected void onPause(){...}
```

I also call setResult(RESULT_OK,i); into this onPause but I always get RESULT_CANCELED and data==null at 'Activity A's onActivityResult

Answer (score 9):

Instead of onBackPressed you can use:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        //set result and finish()

    } else { 
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot pjanecze! You're right.
Doing the setResult(...) and finish() in the onKeyDown(...), before, onPause works!
I think that the key here is that doing the mentined tasks into onPause is too late and neither setResult nor finish will have effect.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the values of the constants you pass to and fro. And they are important.

Here are some pieces of my working code that calls an activity for result:

------------------------------------- **PackVideo** activity --------------------------------------

**calling for ServerSetActivity**

```
Intent serverSetIntent = new Intent();
serverSetIntent.setClass(this, ServerSetActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(serverSetIntent, CHANGE_IP);
```

**constants setting and result catching:** 
(I have them together, because only here in catching both costants meet)

```
static public int CHANGE_IP = 1000;
static public int CHANGE_IP_DONE = 1001;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // If the request was for CHANGE_IP and the request was CHANGE_IP
    if (resultCode == CHANGE_IP_DONE && requestCode == CHANGE_IP) {
        readBaseInfoFromServer(getApplicationContext());
        startVideoPlayerService(getApplicationContext());
        setCurrentChannelAndPlay(getApplicationContext(), 0);
    }
}
```

----------------------------------- **ServerSetActivity** ----------------------------------------

**ending of the called activity**

```
final Intent intent = new Intent();
setResult(PackVideo.CHANGE_IP_DONE, intent);
finish();
```

Comment: Thanks Gangnus  
But the problem are not the constants here.  
I think is more an execution flow problem.  
The question is solved in the first comment of the firts answer.

Comment: Ok, sorry that I wasn't of help :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 2 && data != null) {
//DO YOUR  OVER HERE}
```