# What is the meaning of requestCode in startActivityForResult

Tags: android

I'm wondering if I am understanding the concepts of requestCode correectly. **What is this integer for and does it matter what integer I set it to in**:

```
private static int CAMERA_REQUEST = ???;
```

Thank you

Comment: Here's the dev docs on it: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29

Answer (score 85):

The requestCode helps you to identify from which Intent you came back. For example, imagine your Activity A (Main Activity) could call Activity B (Camera Request), Activity C (Audio Recording), Activity D (Select a Contact).

Whenever the subsequently called activities B, C or D finish and need to pass data back to A, now you need to identify in your onActivityResult from which Activity you are returning from and put your handling logic accordingly.

```
    public static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1;
    public static final int CONTACT_VIEW = 2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedState);
        // For CameraRequest you would most likely do
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

        // For ContactReqeuest you would most likely do
        Intent contactIntent = new Intent(ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("content://contacts/people/1"));
        startActivityForResult(contactIntent, CONTACT_VIEW);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // code to handle cancelled state
        }
        else if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
            // code to handle data from CAMERA_REQUEST
        }
        else if (requestCode == CONTACT_VIEW) {
            // code to handle data from CONTACT_VIEW
        }
    }
```

I hope this clarifies the use of the parameter.

Comment: I understand you answer, but please allow me to discuss some points with you. Is not it enough to identify the from which activity and intent you came back by specifying the intent's name.what i mean is, in the "onActivityResult(..,.., intent data)" we have the parameter "data" which is an intent, is not there any way to get the name of the intent returned back to "onActivityResult"?

Comment: You must test the resultCode agains  RESULT_CANCELED (there is typo in the example),  see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_CANCELED

Comment: Can this request code be literally ANY integer? e.g. a hashcode of an object?

Comment: @treesAreEverywhere No, it must be in the lower 16 bits of an integer. You will get an `IllegalArgumentException`, otherwise.

Comment: Got a reference? -- I trust you, but would still be nice to see some official reference or source? ;-)

Comment: The Exception that @DevDave tells you is thrown with a message that explicitly says that (Like the funny one that asks you if you forgot to declare some Activity to the manifest, which is kind of official). See http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java#FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent%2Cint%29

Answer (score 10):

Look my example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9168458/715269). The integer you have to set can be any one positive. Only do not make them the same, you don't want to mix them, do you? And don't put them to 0 - it is returning without result, IMHO, I had strange behaviours with 0. As for negatives, don't use them, too, they are reserved for negative results in other callActivities functions.

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't know the purpose of it. Is it just an identifier and I can select it randomly?

Comment: yes. It is you, who will read the request code, only *write into* and *compare to* the same values.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Explanation is illustrated in picture.]

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

`app` receives results from the different `intents` via above method only. So how will you understand which intent had replied to you? For that reason, before invoking the intents we put a self defined TAG/Label which is called `requestCode`. By our own defined `requestCODE` we can check which intent's result we have received.

Here in `requestCode` in the example I have given 1001 for Camera Intent. You can put any of your desired number. 1200 or 2001 or 21. Any Positive integers ranging to ~2^16.

See the picture attached.

Answer (score 4):

Using an integer out of the range will raise a "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode" exception.

So keep in mind that request is not just any positive integer but an integer of 16 bits, so from 0 to 65535.

Similarly, validateRequestPermissionsRequestCode in FragmentActivity requires requestCode to be of 8 bits, so between 0 and 255.